# Need suggestion for interval in window service

Tags: c#, vb.net, email, send

I have window service application send email every 10 seconds, But I want to send it in specific date. And I want to send only once/one email only in that day. Do i need to change my 10 seconds to 1Day? or there's any other way.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Threading;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace TestWS
{
    public partial class MyNewService : ServiceBase
    {
        private string from_email = "dcaquino@trends.com.ph";
        private string to_email   = "dcaquino@trends.com.ph";
        //private string cc_email   = "dcaquino@trends.com.ph";
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        public MyNewService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CanStop = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(sendmail);
            timer.Interval = 10000; // 15 min
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Start();
            //timer.Enabled = true;
            //timer.Interval = 10000;
            //timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }

        //--------TIMER----//
        protected void timer_Elapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs aa)
        {
            check_contract();
        }

        //---------SEND EMAIL AND CHECK FOR THE CONTRACT END DATE-------//
        private void check_contract()
        {
            string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;database=scms;port=3306;password=;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            conn.Open();
            string query = "select a.contract_end,a.contract_id,b.title from contracts a join clients b on a.client_id = b.id";
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter ad1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            ad1.Fill(dt1);

            string querycount = "select count(contract_end) from contracts";
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(querycount, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter ad2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            ad2.Fill(dt2);
            int count_dates = Convert.ToInt16(dt2.Rows[0][0].ToString());

            for (int i = 0; i < count_dates; i++)
            {
                DateTime c_end = Convert.ToDateTime(dt1.Rows[i][0]);
                DateTime c_end_30 = c_end.AddDays(-30);
                DateTime c_end_15 = c_end.AddDays(-15);
                DateTime c_end_10 = c_end.AddDays(-10);
                string c_id = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[i][1]);
                string client_name = Convert.ToString(dt1.Rows[i][2]);
                string format = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
                string date_expired = Convert.ToDateTime(dt1.Rows[i][0]).ToString(format);
                if (c_end_30 == DateTime.Today)
                {
                    sendemail(c_id, client_name, date_expired,"30 Days");
                }
                else if(c_end_15 == DateTime.Today)
                {
                    sendemail(c_id, client_name, date_expired, "15 Days");
                }
                else if (c_end_10 == DateTime.Today)
                {
                    sendemail(c_id, client_name, date_expired, "10 Days");
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        private void sendemail(string c_id, string client_name, string date_expired,string days_remain)
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(from_email);
                MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(to_email);
                //MailAddress ccAddress = new MailAddress(ccAddress);

                message.From = fromAddress;
                message.To.Add(toAddress);
                //message.CC.Add(ccAddress);
                message.Subject = "Contract Expiration -SCMS";
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = "Hello Account Manager, <br /> <br /> <br />" +
                               "Contract will expired on " + date_expired +
                               "<br /><br />Days Remaining: " + days_remain +
                               "<br /><br />Contract Number: " + c_id +
                               "<br /><br />Client Name: " + client_name +
                               "<br /><br /><br /><br />Please prepare for necessary steps to update the client for renewal of contract. <br/>" +
                               "<br /><br /><br />Message from SCMS";

                smtpClient.Host = "10.10.20.20";
                smtpClient.Port = 25;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("dcaquino@trends.com.ph", "@dca12345");
                smtpClient.Send(message);
                smtpClient.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(smtpClient.ServicePoint.ConnectionName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Please remove all code not directly related to the question

Comment: already edit thanks....

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is a cron job type of code I would suggest this post

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/10/an-event-based-cron-scheduled-job-in-c/

In there you will find a link for [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) which I have used in Java and it is very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the date and time that you last send mail in the registry (or config file).

Read that value when the service starts in in your timer check to see how long since you last sent mail:

```
'At Startup
Dim lastSend as DateTime = ReadFromRegistry

'In a Timer
If (DateTime.Now - lastSend).TotalDays >= 1 Then
    'send mail   
    lastSend = DateTime.Now
    'store lastSend in registry
End If
```

Comment: can you edit my code or be more specific I'm slightly confused..thanks